# A*(A-star) algorithm gives wrong path and crashes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, data-structures, graph, a-star

I'm implementing A*(A-star) algorithm in react.js but my program crashes whenever  startNode(green) or destinationNode(blue) have more than one neighbour or if there is a cycle in the graph. There is something wrong when adding and deleting the neighbours from/to openList or when updating the parentId in the getPath() function. I cant even see the console because the website goes down.
Each node has: id, name, x, y, connectedToIdsList:[], gcost:Infinity, fcost:0, heuristic:0, parentId:null.
I'm sending the path to another component "TodoList" which prints out the path. My program should not return the path but keeps updating the path as i'm adding nodes and edges to the list. Please help, I've been stuck for hours now:/

My code:

```html
export default class TurnByTurnComponent extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { shortestPath: [] }
    }


    render() {
        const {
            destinationLocationId,
            locations,
            originLocationId
        } = this.props;
        let path = []

        if (destinationLocationId != null && originLocationId != null) {

            if (originLocationId == destinationLocationId) { //check if the startNode node is the end node
                return originLocationId;
            }

            var openList = [];
            let startNode = getNodeById(originLocationId);
            let destinationNode = getNodeById(destinationLocationId)
            if (startNode.connectedToIds.length > 0 && destinationNode.connectedToIds.length > 0) { //check if start and destination nodes are connected first

                startNode.gcost = 0
                startNode.heuristic = manhattanDistance(startNode, destinationNode)
                startNode.fcost = startNode.gcost + startNode.heuristic;

                //perform A*
                openList.push(startNode); //starting with the startNode 
                while (openList.length > 0) {
                    console.log("inside while")
                    var currentNode = getNodeOfMinFscore(openList); //get the node of the minimum f cost of all nodes in the openList
                    if (currentIsEqualDistanation(currentNode)) {
                        path = getPath(currentNode);
                    }
                        deleteCurrentFromOpenList(currentNode, openList);
                    for (let neighbourId of currentNode.connectedToIds) { 
                        var neighbourNode = getNodeById(neighbourId);
                        currentNode.gcost = currentNode.gcost + manhattanDistance(currentNode, neighbourNode);
                        if (currentNode.gcost < neighbourNode.gcost) {
                            neighbourNode.parentId = currentNode.id; // keep track of the path
                            // total cost saved in neighbour.g
                            neighbourNode.gcost = currentNode.gcost;
                            neighbourNode.heuristic = manhattanDistance(neighbourNode, destinationNode);
                            neighbourNode.fcost = neighbourNode.gcost + neighbourNode.heuristic; //calculate f cost of the neighbourNode
                            addNeighbourNodeToOpenList(neighbourNode, openList);
                        }
                    }

                }
                path = path.reverse().join("->");
            }
        }

        function addNeighbourNodeToOpenList(neighbourNode, openList) {
            //add neighbourNode to the open list to be discovered later
            if (!openList.includes(neighbourNode)) {
                openList.push(neighbourNode);
            }
        }


        function deleteCurrentFromOpenList(currNode, openList) {
            const currIndex = openList.indexOf(currNode);
            openList.splice(currIndex, 1); //deleting currentNode from openList
        }

        function currentIsEqualDistanation(currNode) {
            //check if we reached out the distanation node
            return (currNode.id == destinationLocationId)
        }

        function getNodeById(nid) {
            var node;
            for (let i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                if (locations[i].id == nid) {
                    node = locations[i]
                }
            }
            return node
        }

       function getPath(destNode) {
        console.log("inside getpath")
        var parentPath = []
        var parent;
        while (destNode.parentId != null) {
            parentPath.push(destNode.name)
            parent = destNode.parentId;
            destNode = getNodeById(parent);
        }
        //adding startNode to the path
        parentPath.push(getNodeById(originLocationId).name)
        return parentPath;
    }

        function getNodeOfMinFscore(openList) {
            var minFscore = openList[0].fcost; //initValue
            var nodeOfminFscore;
            for (let i = 0; i < openList.length; i++) {
                if (openList[i].fcost <= minFscore) {
                    minFscore = openList[i].fcost //minFvalue
                    nodeOfminFscore = openList[i]
                }
            }

            return nodeOfminFscore
        }

        //manhattan distance is for heuristic and gScore. Here I use Manhattan instead of Euclidean 
        //because in this example we dont have diagnosal path.
        function manhattanDistance(stNode, dstNode) {
            var x = Math.abs(dstNode.x - stNode.x);
            var y = Math.abs(dstNode.y - stNode.y);
            var dist = x + y;
            return dist;
        }


        return (
            <div className="turn-by-turn-component">
                <TodoList
                    
                    list={"Shortest path: ", [path]}
                />
                <TodoList
                   
                    list={[]}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

TurnByTurnComponent.propTypes = {
    destinationLocationId: PropTypes.number,
    locations: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
        id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        x: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        y: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        connectedToIds: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.number.isRequired).isRequired
    })),
    originLocationId: PropTypes.number
};
```

**Update new issue**
Pictures of before and after linking a new node. When I update the graph and add a new node the path disappears. And sometimes come back and so on if I still add new nodes and edges to the graph. As I said, each node has: id, name, x, y, connectedToIdsList:[], gcost:Infinity, fcost:0, heuristic:0, parentId:null.
**My new code now is:**

```html
export default class TurnByTurnComponent extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { shortestPath: [] }
    }


    render() {
        const {
            destinationLocationId,
            locations,
            originLocationId
        } = this.props;
        let path = []

        if (destinationLocationId != null && originLocationId != null) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(locations))
            path = [getNodeById(originLocationId).namne];
            if (originLocationId != destinationLocationId) {
                var openList = [];
                let startNode = getNodeById(originLocationId);
                let destinationNode = getNodeById(destinationLocationId)
                if (startNode.connectedToIds.length > 0 && destinationNode.connectedToIds.length > 0) {
                    startNode.gcost = 0
                    startNode.heuristic = manhattanDistance(startNode, destinationNode)
                    startNode.fcost = startNode.gcost + startNode.heuristic;

                    openList.push(startNode); //starting with the startNode 
                    while (openList.length > 0) {
                        var currentNode = getNodeOfMinFscore(openList); //get the node of the minimum f cost of all nodes in the openList
                        if (currentIsEqualDistanation(currentNode)) {
                            path = getPath(currentNode);
                            break;
                        }
                        deleteCurrentFromOpenList(currentNode, openList);
                        for (let neighbourId of currentNode.connectedToIds) {
                            var neighbourNode = getNodeById(neighbourId);
                            let gcost = currentNode.gcost + manhattanDistance(currentNode, neighbourNode);
                            if (gcost < (neighbourNode.gcost ?? Infinity)) {
                                neighbourNode.parentId = currentNode.id;
                                // keep track of the path
                                // total cost saved in neighbour.g
                                neighbourNode.gcost = gcost;
                                neighbourNode.heuristic = manhattanDistance(neighbourNode, destinationNode);
                                neighbourNode.fcost = neighbourNode.gcost + neighbourNode.heuristic; //calculate f cost of the neighbourNode
                                addNeighbourNodeToOpenList(neighbourNode, openList);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        path = path.reverse().join("->");

        function addNeighbourNodeToOpenList(neighbourNode, openList) {
            //add neighbourNode to the open list to be discovered later
            if (!openList.includes(neighbourNode)) {
                openList.push(neighbourNode);
            }
        }


        function deleteCurrentFromOpenList(currentNode, openList) {
            const currIndex = openList.indexOf(currentNode);
            openList.splice(currIndex, 1); //deleting currentNode from openList
        }

        function currentIsEqualDistanation(currentNode) {
            //check if we reached out the distanation node
            return (currentNode.id == destinationLocationId)
        }

        function getNodeById(id) {
            var node;
            for (let i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                if (locations[i].id == id) {
                    node = locations[i]
                }
            }
            return node
        }

        function getPath(destinationNode) {
            console.log("inside getpath")
            var parentPath = []
            var parent;
            while (destinationNode.parentId != null) {
                parentPath.push(destinationNode.name)
                parent = destinationNode.parentId;
                destinationNode = getNodeById(parent);
            }
            //adding startNode to the path
            parentPath.push(getNodeById(originLocationId).name)
            return parentPath;
        }

        function getNodeOfMinFscore(openList) {
            var minFscore = openList[0].fcost; //initValue
            var nodeOfminFscore;
            for (let i = 0; i < openList.length; i++) {
                if (openList[i].fcost <= minFscore) {
                    minFscore = openList[i].fcost //minFvalue
                    nodeOfminFscore = openList[i]
                }
            }

            return nodeOfminFscore
        }

        //manhattan distance is for heuristic and gScore. Here I use Manhattan instead of Euclidean 
        //because in this example we dont have diagnosal path.
        function manhattanDistance(startNode, destinationNode) {
            var x = Math.abs(destinationNode.x - startNode.x);
            var y = Math.abs(destinationNode.y - startNode.y);
            var dist = x + y;
            return dist;
        }


        return (

            <div className="turn-by-turn-component">

                <TodoList
                    title="Mandatory work"
                    list={[path]}
                />
                <TodoList
                    title="Optional work"
                    list={[]}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

TurnByTurnComponent.propTypes = {
    destinationLocationId: PropTypes.number,
    locations: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
        id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        x: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        y: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        connectedToIds: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.number.isRequired).isRequired
    })),
    originLocationId: PropTypes.number
};
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239097/discussion-on-question-by-adama-aa-star-algorithm-gives-wrong-path-and-crashe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues in your code:

- `return originLocationId;` should not happen. When the source is equal to the target, then set the path, and make sure the final `return` of this function is executed, as you want to return the `div` element.
- When the target is found in the loop, not only should the `path` be built, but the loop should be *exited*. So add a `break`
- `currentNode.gcost = currentNode.gcost + manhattanDistance(currentNode, neighbourNode);` is not right: you don't want to modify `currentNode.gcost`: its value should not depend on the outgoing edge to that neighbour. Instead store this sum in a temporary variable (like `gcost`)
- The comparison with `neighbourNode.gcost` will not work when that node does not yet have a `gcost` member. I don't see in your code that it got a default value that makes sure this condition is true, so you should use a default value here, like `(neighbourNode.gcost ?? Infinity)`
- `path = path.reverse().join("->");` should better be executed *always*, also when there is no solution (so `path` is a string) or when the source and target are the same node.

Here is a corrected version, slightly adapted to run here as a runnable snippet:

```js
function render() {
    const {
        destinationLocationId,
        locations,
        originLocationId
    } = this.props;
    let path = [];
    
    if (destinationLocationId != null && originLocationId != null) {
        path = [originLocationId]; // The value for when the next if condition is not true 
        if (originLocationId != destinationLocationId) {
            var openList = [];
            let startNode = getNodeById(originLocationId);
            let destinationNode = getNodeById(destinationLocationId)
            if (startNode.connectedToIds.length > 0 && destinationNode.connectedToIds.length > 0) {

                startNode.gcost = 0
                startNode.heuristic = manhattanDistance(startNode, destinationNode)
                startNode.fcost = startNode.gcost + startNode.heuristic;
                
                openList.push(startNode);
                while (openList.length > 0) {
                    var currentNode = getNodeOfMinFscore(openList);
                    if (currentIsEqualDistanation(currentNode)) {
                        path = getPath(currentNode);
                        break; // Should end the search here!
                    }
                    deleteCurrentFromOpenList(currentNode, openList);
                    for (let neighbourId of currentNode.connectedToIds) { 
                        var neighbourNode = getNodeById(neighbourId);
                        // Should not modify the current node's gcost. Use a variable instead:
                        let gcost = currentNode.gcost + manhattanDistance(currentNode, neighbourNode);
                        // Condition should also work when neighbour has no gcost yet:
                        if (gcost < (neighbourNode.gcost ?? Infinity)) {
                            neighbourNode.parentId = currentNode.id;
                            neighbourNode.gcost = gcost; // Use the variable
                            neighbourNode.heuristic = manhattanDistance(neighbourNode, destinationNode);
                            neighbourNode.fcost = neighbourNode.gcost + neighbourNode.heuristic;
                            addNeighbourNodeToOpenList(neighbourNode, openList);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Convert the path to string in ALL cases:
    path = path.reverse().join("->");

    function addNeighbourNodeToOpenList(neighbourNode, openList) {
        if (!openList.includes(neighbourNode)) {
            openList.push(neighbourNode);
        }
    }


    function deleteCurrentFromOpenList(currNode, openList) {
        const currIndex = openList.indexOf(currNode);
        openList.splice(currIndex, 1);
    }

    function currentIsEqualDistanation(currNode) {
        return (currNode.id == destinationLocationId)
    }

    function getNodeById(nid) {
        var node;
        for (let i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            if (locations[i].id == nid) {
                node = locations[i]
            }
        }
        return node
    }

    function getPath(destNode) {
        var parentPath = []
        var parentId;
        while (destNode.parentId != null) {
            parentPath.push(destNode.name)
            parentId = destNode.parentId;
            destNode = getNodeById(parentId);
        }
        parentPath.push(getNodeById(originLocationId).name)
        return parentPath;
    }

    function getNodeOfMinFscore(openList) {
        var minFscore = openList[0].fcost;
        var nodeOfminFscore;
        for (let i = 0; i < openList.length; i++) {
            if (openList[i].fcost <= minFscore) {
                minFscore = openList[i].fcost
                nodeOfminFscore = openList[i]
            }
        }

        return nodeOfminFscore
    }

    function manhattanDistance(stNode, dstNode) {
        var x = Math.abs(dstNode.x - stNode.x);
        var y = Math.abs(dstNode.y - stNode.y);
        var dist = x + y;
        return dist;
    }

    return "Shortest path: " + path;
}

// Demo
let props = {
    locations: [
        { id: 1, x: 312, y: 152, connectedToIds: [4,2], name: "Thetaham" },
        { id: 2, x: 590, y: 388, connectedToIds: [1,3], name: "Deltabury" },
        { id: 3, x: 428, y: 737, connectedToIds: [2], name: "Gammation" },
        { id: 4, x: 222, y: 430, connectedToIds: [1], name: "Theta City" },
    ],
    originLocationId: 1,
    destinationLocationId: 3, 
};

console.log(render.call({props}));
```

Comment: trincot, Thank you! You don't know how much that helped me!
But I still have an issue. After I get some path, if I add a new node and connect it to the graph, the path disappears. The best path should be updated no matter how many new nodes/edges I add to the graph. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. If `render` is called with a different (possibly extended) `locations` array, it just starts from scratch, without regard for a path that might have been returned before.

Comment: im going to add a new picture to explain the issue more.

Comment: Please check the last update @trincot